# What is "Loan principal"?

Tags: meaning

I'm using an English financial application to keep track of my spending. When trying to categorize a transaction as a student loan payout, the closest built-in category I could find was "Loan Principal Received". What does that mean? The definition ([according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3a%20loan%20principal)) is

> The total sum of money borrowed

If I receive monthly student loans throughout a year, would it be correct to categorize those "income" transactions as "loan principal received"? Would it be more correct to create my own category and call it "loan payout"?

Comment: Read it as "the principal amount of the loan" (total sum of money borrowed). The amounts you get throughout the year are part of the principal. The amount eventually payable would include principal and interest.

Comment: @Kris: What would you call transactions that are part of the principal? Is simply "loan payout" the best way to describe them?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'loan payout'. You are to use 'receipts' not 'payouts' in the context.

Comment: @Kris: I'm just looking for a category name for the transactions where I receive student loans. It will probably only ever be read by me, but I want a short name that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *principal* of a loan is the total amount of the loan. With student loans, which are yearly loans, the principal would be that amount, and yes, it is usually broken down monthly. For budgetary purposes (but not for income tax purposes), that is income .

*Loan payout* is fine.

Comment: *principal* is the amount borrowed.  It is distinct from *interest* paid as an annual percentage of the due principal, and and *penalties* or *fees* charged for specific actions.  (If I borrow $1000 to pay my tuition, and make $1500 in total payments, I had $1000 principal and $500 in interest or fees.)

Comment: What do taxes have to do with this at all?  Any accounting system he uses will need to distinguish between monies he is paying back and the increased debt he has due to letting the balance accumulate, or it won't be able to reconcile.  (He isn't concerned with the principal or interest at this point, unless he's making payments.)